# Country restriction iTunes connect

Tags: app-store-connect

Our Apple account have multiple apps(25), for multiple countries (15). I want to share all those apps with a colleague. But this colleague can't download the apps because of the country restrictions. I also don't want to build 25 apps (which some need old xcode versions and old sdk's)

I tried if you are a admin in your iTunes Connect account to download this app, but it failed. Also I tried to send a existing app by TestFlightApp in ITC, but this is also not possible. Also promo codes is not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry to take a side road, but how do you manage releasing the 25 apps? Do you have a release day and do everything manually? Thanks for the input!

Comment: We have 25 different apps under 1 account @andres.cianio

Comment: Thx @Robert-Jan! I'm interested in how to proceed on a release for all 20+ apps. Do you have some kind of automation tool, or do you proceed manually with the submit & release for each app ? Cheers!

Comment: @andres.cianio We submit them one by one manually.

Comment: Yeah... Not looking forward to it. Thanks though!